# Getting resources folder of a web site in java

Tags: java, resources, instagram, downloading-website-files

I'm developing an app to download a photo from instagram, for example:
if I put this uri on the app https://www.instagram.com/p/BASqNR9wrKp/ it download the image on my computer.
What I would like to achieve now is to pass the link of the instagram page (for instance: https://www.instagram.com/microsoft/?hl=it) and download all the photos on that page, how can I achieve that ?

I thought I could access those images from the instagram's Frames folder but I don't know how to do that, some can help me ? any advice ?
That's an image of the folder i'm trying to access via java.

[image: Images folder of instagram's microsoft page]

Answer (score 1):

What you need there is called a Web Crawler. The simplest I can think of in Java is [Crawler4J](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) and, for your specific case, their [Image Crawler](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/tree/master/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/imagecrawler)

Comment: so i cannot access the folder directly ?

Comment: It is not really a folder, the browser just shows the grouped images.

Comment: and where does it get those images from ?

Comment: They are referenced from the following sources:  1) The HTML file 2) The loaded CSS file 3) The loaded javascript files. Most of the time they will be obtained from the same server that has the webpage (Instagram's in this case).